# REST Backend with specified columns, SQL questions

Tags: sql-server, database, rest

I'm working with a new REST backend talking to a SQL Server. Our REST api allows for the caller to pass in the columns/fields they want returned (`?fields=id,name,phone`).

The idea seems very normal. The issue I'm bumping up against is resistance to dynamically generating the SQL statement. Any arguments passed in would be passed to the database using a parameterized query, so I'm not concerned about SQL injection.

The basic idea would be to "inject" the column-names passed in, into a SQL that looks like:

```
SELECT <column-names> 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY <column-name-to-sort-by> 
LIMIT 1000
```

We sanitize all column names and verify their existence in the table, to prevent SQL injection issues. Most of our programmers are used to having all SQL in static files, and loading them from disk and passing them on to the database. The idea of code creating SQL makes them very nervous.

I guess I'm curious if others actually do this?  If so, how do you do this?  If not, how do you manage "dynamic columns and dynamic sort-by" requests passed in?

Comment: Can you elaborate on  - `...is resistance to dynamically generating the SQL statement. Any arguments passed in would be passed to the database using a parameterized query, so I'm not concerned about sql injection. `

Comment: I guess I mixed two different things there:  (1) We sanitize the column names before they are injected into the sql.  (2) We use a parameterized query for values (... WHERE name LIKE @NAME), and pass @NAME via a parameterized query value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a lot of people do it especially when it comes to reporting features. There are actually two things one should do to stay on the safe side:

1. Parameterize all WHERE clause values
2. Use user input values to pick correct column/table names, don't use the user values in the sql statement at all

To elaborate on item #2, I would have a dictionary where Key is a possible user input and Value is a correponding column/table name. You can store this dictionary wherever you want: config file, database, hard code, etc. So when you process user input you just check a dictionary if the Key exists and if it does you use the Value to add a column name to your query. This way you just use user input to pick required column names but don't use the actual values in your sql statement. Besides, you might not want to expose all columns. With a predefined dictionary you can easily control the list of available columns for a user.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar to what Maksym suggests. In my case, keys were pulled directly from the database system tables (after scrubbing the user request a bit for syntactic hacks and permissions).

The following query takes care of some minor injection issues through the natural way SQL handles the LIKE condition. This doesn't go as far as handling permissions on each field (as some fields are forbidden based on the log-in) but it provides a very basic way to retrieve these fields dynamically.

```
CREATE PROC get_allowed_column_names
@input VARCHAR(MAX)
AS BEGIN
SELECT
  columns.name AS allowed_column_name
FROM
  syscolumns AS columns,
  sysobjects AS tables
WHERE
  columns.id = tables.id AND
  tables.name = 'Categories' AND
  @input LIKE '%' + columns.name + '%'
END
GO

-- The following only returns "Picture"
EXEC get_allowed_column_names 'Category_,Cat%,Picture'
GO

-- The following returns both "CategoryID and Picture"
EXEC get_allowed_column_names 'CategoryID, Picture'
GO
```